# SSIS script task (c#) works in Visual Studio well. But when I run it in SSMS it runs succesfully but does nothing

Tags: c#, file, ssis, permissions, ssms

I I prepared a simple `c#` script that can rename a file on my local directory.  When I run it in `visual studio` it completes successfully and rename the file. the code below;

```
public void Main()
{
   // TODO: Add your code here
   string path = @"D:\DataFiles\IQVIAData\BrickWeekly\BrickWeeklyData\201226_FACT_ALL_SALES_147.txt";
   string path2 = @"D:\DataFiles\IQVIAData\BrickWeekly\BrickWeeklyData\ASD.txt";
   File.Move(path, path2);
   Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

From `SSMS` when I execute the `SSIS` package which script task included, it runs and it says succesfully completed but the file is still with the same name and it didn't rename the file.

Here what I did before texting here,

1. I gave permission to folder for everone to modify (full control; read,write...) (İt didn't work)

[image]

2. I created a SSIS proxy which refers my admin account and run the script instead sql server agent. (It didn't work)
   [image]
3. I changed the folder path randomly which does not exist like that path. When I run it visual studio gave error like; there is no folder with this name etc... This was what I expect it. After that I deployed the package to `sql server` and run the package from `SSMS`. But it didnt give me any error despite there is a mistake with folder path. It runs succusfully.

   ```
   public void Main()
   {
       // TODO: Add your code here
       string path = @"D:\DataFiles\IQVIAData\BrickWeekly\BrickWeeklyData\201226_FACT_ALL_SALES_147.txt";
       string path2 = @"D:\DataFiles\IQVIAData\BrickWeekly\asdasd\ASD.txt";
       File.Move(path, path2);
       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   }
   ```

Any ideas or advice to solve my problem?

Comment: Is file being access by another application?  Windows will not move a file if another app is using the file.

Comment: Actually there is no other application use the file. I create the file with SSIS then trying to rename the file in the work flow. When I see it does not work, I created another script task in a different SSIS package which can rename. When I run it from SSMS there is no other application which using the file. I am pretty sure about it.

Comment: If you create the file you have to make sure you close and dispose the write stream before moving.  The code that writes should be in a Using block so when code exits the block the object gets disposed.

Comment: It closes the file. If it doesnt close, I can not run the script from visual studio succesfully.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  Files can be shared with read only access which will stop moving.   The running of the script can also prevent file from being moved.

Comment: Then, what is your opinion about SSMS runs script which includes wrong path name? It must give an error.

Comment: SSMS is closing file before moving.  SSMS could be reading file into memory and closing before executing.  SSMS is designed to be multi-threaded and multi-user so it tries to be very safe to preventing cross threading issue.

Comment: What is the "On failure action" set to on the Advanced tab of your second screenshot. It should be set to "Quit the job reporting failure". If it was accidentally set to "Quit the job reporting success", the job would not show a failure.

Comment: It sets Quit the job reporting failure

Comment: At the top of the method, below the TODO line, add this:
`bool fireAgain = true;
Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task", "Line executed successfully.", String.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);`
Then deploy the project again and execute it. After it finishes, please check the execution log for that project to see if that message was logged.

Comment: What else is in the SSIS package?

Comment: @billinkc there is nothing else

Comment: @JoeS I added it and deployed but the message was not logged after I run it. I don't think it runs the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with viusal studio, maybe it is about settings. Bu I couldn't figure out. I installed visual studio 2019 and create the package with it. After deployment It worked properly. Thanks for advices.

Comment: Must have been something odd in the installation. It could be that the project was deployed with the wrong SQL Server version. If you right click the project and go to Properties, under the Configuration Properties>General page, there is a TargetServerVersion property. This needs to be set to the SQL Server version being deployed to, otherwise script tasks do not work correctly. That could have been part of it, but not sure. Glad it's working for you now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As I eluded to in my comment, this may have been the issue, and I thought I should add this as an answer for anyone else coming across this question:

When SSIS projects are deployed to the SSIS catalog, there is a SQL Server version that needs to be set on the Visual Studio project. It is in the project properties under Configuration Properties > General, named TargetServerVersion.

[image]

It should be set to the correct version of the deployment server. Otherwise, tasks/components, especially script tasks/components, may not function correctly. Most of the time it will throw a version error on the server, but I have seen packages execute successfully without executing the script task/component.

There is a bug in one of the versions of either VS 2019 or the SSIS extension where the TargetServerVersion in the dialog does not reflect what the project is actually set to. This occurs when importing an SSIS project from a server. I usually go into that setting, change it to SQL Server 2019, and then back to my target version (in this case, SQL Server 2016). This forces the project to the correct version.

Hope this helps.